# On content click -> hide div -> hiding unwanted materialize datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, onclick, materialize

I'm having trouble with a function which closes a popup div on outside content click, which goes something like:

```
$('#content').on('click',function(event){
let hide_this = $('#hide_this');

let dont_hide_when_clicking_this = $('.dont_hide_when_clicking_this');
let materialize_date_picker = $('[class*=datepicker]').find('*');

if(!$(event.target).is(dont_hide_when_clicking_this) && !$(event.target).is(materialize_date_picker)) {
    hide_this.hide()
   }
}
```

To avoid hiding the div on clicking targets which should not trigger the hide action I use `!$(event.target).is(date_picker)`.

Which is fine in all elements but doesn't work in some of Materialize datepicker's divs, specifically on the days. Which unwontedly triggers the `.hide()`.

Does anyone know how should I go about it?